# PHP - Multiple delimiter implode

Tags: php, arrays, explode, delimiter, implode

I want to implode a string with multiple delimiters. I've already eplode it with this PHP function:

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
$exploded = multiexplode(array(",",".","|",":"),$text);
```

The output of this is:

```
Array (
   [0] => here is a sample
   [1] =>  this text
   [2] =>  and this will be exploded
   [3] =>  this also 
   [4] =>  this one too 
   [5] => )
)
```

Can I implode this array with the following multiple delimiters: `,` `.` `|` `:` ?

**Edit:**

For define the rules I think this is the best option:

```
$test = array(':', ',', '.', '|', ':');
$i = 0;
foreach ($exploded as $value) {
    $exploded[$i] .= $test[$i];
    $i++;
}
$test2 = implode($exploded);
```

The output of `$test2` is:

```
here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)
```

I only now need to know how to define the `$test` array (maybe with `preg_match()`?) so that it matched these values `,` `.` `|` `:` and set the variables in a order where it occurs in the string into an array. Is this possible?

Comment: you need to define the rules how delimiters should be applied.

Comment: For the array you got from explode, if you wanted to implode using 4 characters(`,` `.` `|` and `:`), how would you expect the results to look like?

Comment: @mario How should a solution like you have suggested look like? IMHO it is easy to remove multiple delimiters - as shown - but impossible to craft the method `multiimplode()`

Comment: @hek2mgl True, I completely overlooked what OP was about. It's obviously not a reversible process.

Comment: @mario OK.. If you would have presented me a way I would had eaten a bear. (or something like this ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl See my edit how to define the rules, I think this is a possible solution, I only now need to set the variables in a order where it occurs in the string into an array.

Comment: @zfus I expect that the results look the same as the `$text` variable.

Comment: @mario See my edit, is it still then not a reversible process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$string = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
echo "Input:".PHP_EOL.$string;

$needle = array(",",".","|",":");
$split = multiexplode($needle, $string);

$chars = implode($needle);
$found = array();

while (false !== $search = strpbrk($string, $chars)) {
    $found[] = $search[0];
    $string = substr($search, 1);
}

echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Found needle:".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
print_r($found);

$i = 0;
foreach ($split as $value) {
    $split[$i] .= $found[$i];
    $i++;
}

$output = implode($split);
echo PHP_EOL."Output:".PHP_EOL.$output;
```

The output of this is:

```
Input:
here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)

Found needle:

Array
(
    [0] => :
    [1] => ,
    [2] => .
    [3] => |
    [4] => :
)

Output:
here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)
```

You can see it working [here](https://eval.in/65726).

For more information what's the function of `strpbrk` in this script, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743373/finding-the-correct-occurrence-order#answer-18743588).

It's my first contribution to Stack Overflow, hope it helps.