# PHP: Explode array, include all tags (not just paragraph)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that takes the content from the Wordpress post and injects an image between each count of a paragraph - this works well.

It does not take into account heading or image tags etc. How can I modify this so it does take these other tags into the count?

```
<?php
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        
        $content_table = explode("<p>", $content);

        $content_table[3] .= $spot1;
        $content_table[6] .= $spot2;
        $content_table[9] .= $spot3;
        $content_table[12] .= $spot4;
        $content_table[15] .= $spot5;

        $content2 = implode($content_table, "<p>");
        
        echo $content2;
?>
```

Comment: may be explode with new line

Comment: Maybe use something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686628/php-multiple-delimiter-implode to specify the tags to implode by?

Comment: I can explode but implode by keeping the tags is causing an issue